# How to separate a custom library in vendor.js and load it as a separate file specifically on click of link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am adding a custom library in the vendor.js file due to which the size of file is increasing like more than 10mb and hence need to come up with a solution to separately load this custom library. so when I think of loading this custom library, the questions are how to separate it and what are the ways to load it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4638) useful for my scenario. This piece of code below helped

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        minChunks: (m) => /node_modules/.test(m.context)
    }),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'react-router',
            minChunks: (m) => /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react-router)[\\/]/.test(m.context)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Code splitting is one of the most compelling features of webpack that I like :

we have modules in the key `entry` here :

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    another: './src/another-module.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

webpack will automatically create separated file for your modules :

```
        Asset     Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
another.bundle.js  550 KiB  another  [emitted]  another
  index.bundle.js  550 KiB    index  [emitted]  index
```

check this [link](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) for more details :